# Go Kafka - Config Value

Tags: go

I am working with Go-Kafka (https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka#ConfigMap.Get) and having trouble with the GET method of ConfigMap.

The docs say that Get needs a key and a defval (of type ConfigValue), but I cannot work out how to create a ConfigValue to pass in.

Here is what I have tried:

```
    configFile := os.Args[1]
    conf := ReadConfig(configFile)
    
    x := conf["sasl.password"]

    fmt.Printf(conf.Get("sasl.password", x))
```

```
    configFile := os.Args[1]
    conf := ReadConfig(configFile)
    
    x := kafka.ConfigValue("Test")

    fmt.Printf(conf.Get("sasl.password", x))
```

But each time I get the same error:

`Cannot use 'conf.Get("sasl.password", x)' (type (ConfigValue, error)) as the type (string, any) or string`

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of your use of `ConfigMap.Get` you aren't doing anything wrong, per se.

Rather the error you are seeing is due to your use of `fmt.Printf`.

The immediate error is because `Get()` returns a value and an error (`(ConfigValue, error)`) which you are trying to pass directly into `Printf()` which expects a string containing format specifiers and a variadic list of any values to be substituted into those format specs.

You first need to get the `ConfigMap` value and test for any error:

```golang
   v, err := conf.Get("sasl.password", x)
   if err != nil {
      // handle/return the error
   }
```

Then if `err` is nil you can output the value using a `%s` spec to `Printf` and passing in the returned value:

```golang
   if err == nil {
      fmt.Printf("%s", v)
   }
```